# Oracle sql - display if record exists else display parent

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to categorize data into two types based on:

If a value exists in T2, display "A", else display "B" as "Type". Is there a way to implement this in case when or decode?

T1 is the parent of T2.

```
T1 
1
2
3
4
5

T2
1
1
3
3
3
4
```

Ideally my output would be

```
Type
A
B
A
A
B
```

edit: I want to add that A and B are text values I want to display based on my above condition, this is not coming from the db. Also, T2 will not have a corresponding record at all for 2 & 5. so I cannot really check for null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.Col, 
       CASE WHEN T2.Col IS NOT NULL THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END AS Type
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT Col FROM T2
) AS T2 ON T1.Col = T2.Col
```

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 ( column_name ) AS
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 6;

CREATE TABLE t2 ( column_name ) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT NVL2( T2.column_name, 'A', 'B' ) AS Type
FROM   T1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       ( SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM T2 ) T2
       ON T1.column_name = T2.column_name
ORDER BY T1.column_name;
```

**Output**:

```
TYPE
----
A    
B    
A    
A    
B
```